# How to test script for endOfMonth function?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Script that logs web server data every 15 minutes.  Created script to log data monthly; then at the end of the month start a new sheet and continue logging.  This should continue year after year.

Is there a way to check if the script will actually create a new sheet at the end of the month?

[Gist of Google Script](https://gist.github.com/Tech500/866412b7cc91c53770103ccf78bcb049)

William

Answer (score 1):

End of Current Month

```
function eom() {
  const dt = new Date();
  Logger.log(new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth() + 1,0))
}
```

Comment: Clarification:  I have a sheet for the current month.  Requesting way to generate sheet for following month.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  How can you expect someone to create a sheet with absolutely no information

Comment: Sheet I was referencing is the one in the "Gist of Google Script" link.  My apologies.  Looking for way of testing the endOFMonth function; instead of waiting a month only to find out the function is not working.

Comment: Just rewrite and replace now.getDate() with a parameter of the same type

Comment: Well it's pretty simple set now equal to the end of a month and run the function and see if it creates a new sheet.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Cooper; task accomplished.